# How to convert or cast INT into a date in SQL Server 18

Tags: sql-server, datetime

This is not a new question, but what worked for SQL Server 2008, seems not to work for newer versions.

I used this approach:

```
select cast(40835 as datetime)
```

and then convert to a date (SQL 2008)

```
select cast(cast(40835 as datetime) as date)
```

I tried a number of things, but none of them worked.
Any ideas what needs to be changed?

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8),sm.[scheme_end_date_key] ))AS [scheme_end_date_key]
```

or

```
 CAST(CAST(sm.[scheme_end_date_key] AS VARCHAR (8)) AS DATETIME) AS [scheme_end_date_key]
```

and then

```
 CAST(CAST([scheme_end_date_key] AS DATETIME) AS DATE) AS [scheme_end_date_key]
```

The errors I get are:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

or

> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Comment: The statement `select cast(cast(40835 as datetime) as date)` works for me in SQL Server 2019, it returns 2011-10-21

Comment: no, does not work for me: Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Comment: I want to be able to join this with a date variable

Comment: What is the datatype of scheme_end_date_key?  If it is char , try 
select cast ( CAST(CAST(scheme_end_date_key AS int) AS DATETIME) as date) from table

Comment: What does 40835 represent? An integer is not a date

Comment: BTW,SQL Server 2008 is dead; it is out of extended support.

Comment: @Charlieface it's leveraging secret knowledge about SQL Server's date/datetime type implementation, that being that the integer portion represents the number of days since 1900-01-01. But it's not a safe assumption because it's undocumented and could change on different platforms.

Comment: `select cast(cast(40835 as datetime) as date)` also returns `2011-10-21` for me on SQL Serve 2019

Comment: "seems not to work for newer versions" what newer version exactly? Also please specify the data type of `[scheme_end_date_key]`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Then what is wrong with the much more resilient `dateadd(day, 40835, '1900-01-01')`

Comment: There's a number of instances where code posted here works fine in our environment but not yours. Please run `SELECT @@VERSION, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases WHERE name = DB_NAME()` and actually specify what this newer version is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those integers are day counts since '1900-01-01' in SQL Server.

Have you tried this?

```
 select CAST(dateadd(day, 40835, '1900-01-01') AS DATE)
```

I like it because it's less obscure and magicnumbery.

Comment: nope: Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/ offers ways to test on SQL Server 2014, 2016, 2017, and 2019. Both your formulation and the one in this answer work correctly on all those versions. With respect, something else is wrong on your end.